# How to disable form button when using [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"?

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I'am using template driven form and two way biding. In the other hand I also use the **`[ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"`** without assigning  a **`name`** attribute to the input fields.

`<app-input [type]="'text'" 
            [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
            [(ngModel)]="data.user.name"
            labelText="User Name" [required]="false"
            [readonly]="false">
</app-input>`

So far the form works fine.

My issue is that I want to disable the button till the form is valid:

```
<button [disabled]="!form.valid" ...>
```

but unfortunately this can not be done when using `[ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"` as the fields are not part of the form then.

I have been searching but didn't find a use case like the one I'am facing.

P.S. The input is an own component using `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`

Comment: instead of adding disabled on the button add it on the input itself

Comment: So you have a form, but one of it's inputs is standalone, but you still want it to count towards form validity? Why would it be standalone then? What makes the standalone inputs even (in)valid?

Comment: @RobertoZvjerkovic: I have to use the inputs as standAlone and without name attribute, otherwise my two way binding which is fetching data from a response object won't work as expected. The input can't be empty e.g. or other inputs which suing specific patterns should match the defined patterns etc.

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I don't really understand what would this bring. I don't want to disable the field, but the button. Could pls. provide a clarification what you exactly mean.

Comment: Just don't use ngmodel, use reactive forms.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerkovic: If I would use reactive form, this would mean I have to change the whole concept (ts and html) which I do not want to do.

Comment: Then you will have to manually do all that. `[disabled]="!form.valid && data.user.name"` etc.

Comment: But that's exactly what reactive forms are there for, so yeah, you should change the structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193624/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-roberto-zvjerkovic).